# How can I always return the current page the user is on in a Request Mapping in Spring MVC?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Spring-Newbie here.

I have a Login Popup which can be opened at the Header of my page. If the Login is successful, I redirect to the index page, that works. If the Login attempt returns with an error, I want to remain on the same page an just display the error inside the Login-Popup.

The Login is submitted by a HTML-Form to the according Request Mapping.

Now I struggle with surpressing the redirect. I pass the destination html page inside the controller on as a string, and am trying now to always "redirect" to the current page the user is on.

I may don't even need a redirect here, just a refresh, but don't know how else to solve it atm.

The Controller code looks like this.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String login(@ModelAttribute("loginForm") @Valid LoginFormModel login,
        BindingResult result,
        Model model,
        HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response,
        HttpSession session) {

    if (result.hasErrors()) {
        setLoginError(login, model, request, session);
        return "index"; // here is where I don't want to redirect to the index in case of error
    }
}
```

I use Thymeleaf as Templating Framework.

I was also thinking of getting the URL from the request, but found only the destination URI not the source in the object.

Comment: Are you using jsp or thymeleaf? please share your setLoginError method and also provide your web page code on how you're displaying error!

Comment: @sbsatter edited accordingly

Comment: Please check these two resources:
http://zetcode.com/spring/bindingresult/
https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/springsecurity.html

Comment: @sbsatter thanks, I know these resources. The difference in my implementation ist that I can login from ANY page (because the Login Popup can be accessed in the general Header of the web page) and should be able to return again to any page. In the resources it's always return to the same page, which I already have but want to change.

Comment: You can use the request headers to identify where the user is trying to log in from, then programmatically return that page. However, in this case, it is rather wise to use an ajax call so that you can send back a json with the error and then display the error using javascript

Answer (score 0):

You can use this solution:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String login(@ModelAttribute("loginForm") @Valid LoginFormModel login,
                    BindingResult result,
                    Model model,
                    HttpServletRequest request,
                    HttpServletResponse response,
                    HttpSession session) throws IOException {

    if (result.hasErrors()) {
        response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath() + request.getRequestURI());
        return null;
    }
}
```

You will return null(no view) in case of error, but request will be redirected according to the response object(pure servlet functionality):

```
 response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath() + request.getRequestURI());
```

You can try to omit request.getContextPath() if your urls don't have any context prefix(root context).

Comment: thanks, but this doesn't work for me since ich have no GET Request Mapping for the requested source